# Android: Problemas con AsyncTask al lanzar elementos

Tags: android

tengo un problema lo que pasa es que creo un intent despues lo inicio y al final se debe de destruit el MainActivity pero todoo ese proceso me esta marcando error porque estoy en la clase SearchData y no en MainActivity de igual forma con el alertDialogBuilder y el txtCode estan marcando error porque esos elementos pertenecen a MainActivity entonces no se como solucionar esos errores lei algo de Context pero no le estoy entendiendo bien y no se si con eso se pueda todoo esto esta en AsyncTask que esta en una clase independiente.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(CheckIn result) {//se ejecuta cuando termina doingBackgroud()
    frameLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    if (result != null){
        Intent intentIndex = new Intent(MainActivity.this, IndexActivity.class);//Creo un intent
        startActivity(intentIndex);//inicio la actividad
        finish();//se destruye la actividad
    } else {
        System.out.println("primer error");
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("ERROR..").setMessage("El codigo no se encontro").setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("ACEPTAR", null).show(); //mensaje si no existe el checkin
        txtCode.setText("");
    } //./else
}
```

Comment: Agrega los errores que te muestra en tu LogCat, y como consejo no imprimas con System, acostumbrate a imprimir con la clase Log

Comment: Tu clase SearchData es un activity?

Comment: En la clase SearchData unicamente tengo a mi AsyncTask entonces no es una actividad porque no implementa de appCompactActivity

Comment: extiende perdon

Comment: ¿Que clase invoca a SearchData?

Comment: lo invoca MainActivity

Answer (score 2):

En tu clase SearchData debes crear una interfaz

```
 public interface TaskListener {
   //Declara como parametro los elementos que necesites
   public void onPostExecute(CheckIn result);
}
```

Ve a tu MainActivity e implementa a esta interfaz

```
 public class MainActivity implements TaskListener{
   //Sobreescribe al método

   @Override
   public void onPostExecute(CheckIn result){

       //Invoca a tu siguiente activity

    if (result != null){
      Intent intentIndex = new Intent(MainActivity.this,  IndexActivity.class);

       //Creo un intent
       startActivity(intentIndex);//inicio la actividad
       finish();//se destruye la actividad
    } else {
       Log.d("TAG", "primer error");
       alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("ERROR..").setMessage("El codigo no se encontro").setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("ACEPTAR", null).show(); //mensaje si no existe el checkin
    txtCode.setText("");
    }
   }
 }
```

A tu clase SearchData le mandas la referencia de tu TaskListener:

//Ejemplo

```
SearchData searchData = new SearchData(this); //Dependiendo de cuantos parametros tengas
searchData.execute();
```

En tu clase SearchData

```
 // Declaras a tu listener
 private TaskListener listener;

 //Constructor
 public SearchData(TaskListener listener){
    this.listener = listener;
 }
```

En el onPostExecute dentro de tu SearchData Declaras lo siguiente:

```
 @Override
 public void onPostExecute(CheckIn result){
    if(listener != null){
     listener.onPostExecute(result);
    }
 }
```

Espero que te sirva

Saludos.

Comment: Perdon Keops por no responder, intente de otra forma investigando encontre que se puede enviar el contexto y si me quedo pero despues lo realize como comentaste y tambien funciono pero siento que es mas laborioso. Agradesco mucho que me estes ayudando.

Answer (score 0):

En mi clase MainActivity.java llamo a mi AsyncTask y le paso como parametro mi Contexto

```
SearchData search = new SearchData(MainActivity.this);
search.execute(...);
```

Finalmente en el constructor de mi SearchData que es donde tengo el AsyncTask lo obtengo

```
public SearchData(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
}
```